# How to fix spiraling during retopology?

Tags: modeling, edges, retopology

I was following tutorial on retopology, and somehow, I ended up with spiral topology throughout the bottom half of the model. I am not animating the character but posing. I don't want it to be a hassle during UV unwrapping.

[image]

[image]

I have open gaps like this and wondering how I can connect the loops.
[image]